# PhantomJS not rendering visible overflow of SVG

Tags: svg, phantomjs, overflow, casperjs, capture

I capture my SVG elements using CasperJS and PhantomJS 2.1.1, but PhantomJS is not rendering the overflow of the SVG which is set to `overflow: visible`.  I want to know is there any setting that I should enable for that purpose?

This is my page:

[image]

and this is captured image:

[image]

and this is my CasperJS code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    viewportSize: {
        width: 1000,
        height: 400
    }
});

var url = 'http://localhost:4000/embed?' + casper.cli.options.url;

casper.start(url, function() {
    casper.waitForResource(function testResource(resource) {
        return resource.url.indexOf("/charts") != -1;
    }, function onReceived() {
        this.wait(4000, function(){
            this.evaluate(function(){
                $('.fa-camera, .fa-code, .fa-question-circle').remove();

                $('body').append('<span style="z-index:99999;position:absolute;bottom:30px;left:35px;">' + moment().format('MMM DD, YYYY') + '</span>');
            });

            this.echo(this.captureBase64('png'));
            this.exit(0);
        });
    });
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, except with regular HTML elements.  :-(

Comment: @AndrewMiner Hi, I am using electron.js now, it works perfectly and very fast. You can try it. Only thing needed is to have display protocol on your server